# Find the number equal or greater than x in a Fibonacci sequence

Tags: algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

Given the following Fibonacci sequence where `a1 = 4` and `a2 = 8`

```
4, 8, 12, 20, 32, 52, 84, 136, 220, 356, 576, 932, 1508, 2440, 3948, 6388
```

And a random number: `63`

It is possible to get the position (in this case `7` because `84` is the next number greater or equal than `63` in the sequence)?

Comment: Hint: the general term for a Fibonacci sequence is $a_n=c_1(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1)^n}{2}+c_2(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})^n$, where you can solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$ with the initial conditions.